# How to cache okHTTP response from Web server?

Tags: java, android, caching, okhttp, etag

I want to know how can okHTTP response from Web server (which returns json data) be cached?

I want my app to download all the data needed for RecycleView and cache it once the user runs the app first time - and avoid re-downloading and parsing all the same data from Web server, if data has not changed.

I tried to get response headers, but this is what I get:

```
Request URL: https://somedomain.com/wp-json/?categories=3&per_page=100&status=publish
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 176.28.12.139:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-WP-Total, X-WP-TotalPages
Allow: GET
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date: Fri, 23 Mar 2018 15:41:23 GMT
Link: <https://somedomain.com/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
Server: nginx
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Powered-By: PleskLin
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.1.15
X-Robots-Tag: noindex
X-WP-Total: 43
X-WP-TotalPages: 1
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: hr,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,de;q=0.7,nb;q=0.6
Connection: keep-alive
Host: somedomain.com
Referer: https://somedomain.com/somedir/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36
categories: 3
per_page: 100
status: publish
```

I have read that I could find **ETAG or Last-Modified** from the Server response to check for any changes, but as you can see there is no such thing.

Do you have any idea what to do if app only needs to download data at the first run - and after that only if the data has changed?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need cache interceptor like this:

```
public class CacheInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());

        CacheControl cacheControl = new CacheControl.Builder()
                .maxAge(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES) // 15 minutes cache
                .build();

        return response.newBuilder()
                .removeHeader("Pragma")
                .removeHeader("Cache-Control")
                .header("Cache-Control", cacheControl.toString())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Add this interceptor with `Cache` to your `OkHttpClient` like this:

```
File httpCacheDirectory = new File(applicationContext.getCacheDir(), "http-cache");
int cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MiB
Cache cache = new Cache(httpCacheDirectory, cacheSize);
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addNetworkInterceptor(new CacheInterceptor())
            .cache(cache)
            .build();
```

Comment: This is working very good, thank you! So basically this creates cache of Server response for 15 minutes? When user runs the app again in like half and hour or so - the app will cache the fresh Server response again for 15 minutes? And one more question - should I use  .cacheControl(CacheControl.FORCE_NETWORK) when building new Request Builder?

Comment: @unipin Yes, this creates cache of Service response for 15 minutes. After 15 minutes app will cache the fresh response. You should use CacheControl.FORCE_NETWORK only if you want to force network request without using cache

Comment: So in this situation if I don't use CacheControl.FORCE_NETWORK, the app will still grab the fresh response - because the cache will vanish? Thank you once again!

Comment: Not working when offline to me. Getting UnknownHostException instead.

Comment: This looks like you are adding logic to intercept and add headers to what the server returns from the Android side. I would highly recommend updating the server side logic to return this max-age header instead of the clients doing it. Read #3 and #5 on this document to better explain what happens (https://medium.com/@I_Love_Coding/how-does-okhttp-cache-works-851d37dd29cd)

Comment: @unipin If this answer worked for you, can you share complete code? I tried this solution but it still sends request to server every time.

Answer (score 3):

Just add a cache to your OkHttp client. 
First, you'll need to create the cache:

```
int cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
Cache cache = new Cache(cacheDirectory, cacheSize);
```

Note that with this code you're providing a cache with a size limit of 10MB. After this, you'll create your client with the following code:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .cache(cache)
    .build();
```

The client will honor cache related headers. You can relate to the official documentation for further details:
https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes

Comment: Thanks for response! This is exactly what I've done in my code - but data is loading with the same speed as in first run. I wonder what to do if Server doesn't respond with cache related headers, like mine above?

Comment: that will require some custom code, then. But before to try to write a solution, let me ask: those are the headers that the server always put to your response, right? The problem is: without any cache related header, you'll have to decide a timeout period for your cache. Have you already thought of this?

Comment: Yes, these headers Server always put in my response. Can you explain what that means, I what are my soultions to this?

Comment: HTTP cache related headers are useful to tell you for how many seconds you should retain your cached value. After that amount of seconds, you should just invalidate the cache. See the link below for a full documentation. Now, in your case, since you have none of those informations, you should decide the expire time on your own, and code it into your app

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control

Comment: Yeah, I can't get those informations from Server. So that's my only option - I set the time when my cache will expire - so app will send the request to the Server no matter if the data hasn't been changed? I believe that data is not changing that much, maybe once in a week, so I guess that's not so bad.