# Caching Images and strings using Retrofit, okhttp and picasso

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp, picasso, cache-control

I'm trying to optimize this code for caching purpose . this code made the cache only for 1 day before it reconnect to internet again to make new cache . I wants to make it for 60 days before it access again to network make new cache . also there is slow down on images which is coming from cache using picasso
picasso:2.5.2
retrofit2:retrofit:2.7.2
retrofit2:converter-gson:2.7.2
okhttp3:okhttp:4.4.1
okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.4.1

````
     if (retrofit==null) {
         OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                 .addInterceptor( provideHttpLoggingInterceptor() )
                 .addInterceptor( provideOfflineCacheInterceptor() )
                 .addNetworkInterceptor( provideCacheInterceptor() )
                 .cache( provideCache() )
                 .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                 .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                 .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                 .build();

         OkHttp3Downloader okHttp3Downloader = new OkHttp3Downloader(okHttpClient);
         Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(MyApplication.getInstance())
                 .downloader(okHttp3Downloader)
                 .build();


         Picasso.setSingletonInstance(picasso);

         retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                 .baseUrl(Global.API_URL)
                 .client(okHttpClient)
                 .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                 .build();
     }
     return retrofit;
 }
 private static Cache provideCache ()
 {
     Cache cache = null;
     try
     {
         cache = new Cache( new File(MyApplication.getInstance().getCacheDir(), "wallpaper-cache" ),
                 100 * 1024 * 1024 ); // 100 MB
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         Timber.e( e, "Could not create Cache!" );
     }
     return cache;
 }
 private static HttpLoggingInterceptor provideHttpLoggingInterceptor ()
 {
     HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor =
             new HttpLoggingInterceptor( new HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger()
             {
                 @Override
                 public void log (String message)
                 {
                     Timber.d( message );
                     Log.v("MYAPI",message);

                 }
             } );
     httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel( BuildConfig.DEBUG ? HEADERS : NONE );
     return httpLoggingInterceptor;
 }
 public static Interceptor provideCacheInterceptor ()
 {
     return new Interceptor()
     {
         @Override
         public Response intercept (Chain chain) throws IOException
         {
             Response response = chain.proceed( chain.request() );
             int maxAge = 60  * 60; // read from cache
             return response.newBuilder()
                     .header( CACHE_CONTROL, "public, max-age=" + maxAge)
                     .removeHeader("Pragma")
                     .build();
         }
     };
 }
 public static Interceptor provideOfflineCacheInterceptor ()
 {
     return new Interceptor()
     {

         @Override
         public Response intercept (Chain chain) throws IOException
         {
             Request request = chain.request();
             if ( !MyApplication.hasNetwork() )
             {
                 int maxStale = 60 * 60 * 24 * 28; // tolerate 4-weeks stale
                 request = request.newBuilder()
                         .header( CACHE_CONTROL,  "public, only-if-cached, max-stale=" + maxStale)
                         .removeHeader("Pragma")
                         .build();
             }
             return chain.proceed( request );
         }
     };
 }

} ```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the cache headers in an interceptor like this example [How to cache okHTTP response from Web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49453564/how-to-cache-okhttp-response-from-web-server)

```
public class CacheInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());

        CacheControl cacheControl = new CacheControl.Builder()
                .maxAge(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES) // 15 minutes cache
                .build();

        return response.newBuilder()
                .removeHeader("Pragma")
                .removeHeader("Cache-Control")
                .header("Cache-Control", cacheControl.toString())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you update me with full code as I don't know if I will change Cache Interceptor or offline cache interceptor or HttpLoggingInterceptor

Comment: Please provide a runnable reproduction that I can open as a project in Intellij. Maybe as a github project and I'll take a look.